# SSH connection to gitlab server not working

Tags: ssh, git, gitlab

I have  recently installed a gitlab server on a Fedora Server VM hosted locally on my computer. To install the gilab server I used this command : `sudo yum install -y gitlab-ce`.

I had no errors during the installation but when I try to connect to the gitlab instance with the command `ssh git@myserver.com` I have this message :

> Last login: Sat Apr 22 16:33:11 2023 from 10.0.2.2.

instead of  :

> Welcome to GitLab, @username!

according to the gitlab documentation.

Also when I try to clone a project I have the following error:

> Clonage dans 'mytestproject'...
> fatal:'Octodex/repositories/mytestproject.git' does not appear to be a git
> repository.
> fatal : Impossible de lire le dépôt distant.
> Veuillez vérifier que vous avez les droits d'accès et que le dépôt
> existe.

The repo I want to clone is a public repo. And I added the generated ssh public key in gitlab.

I don’t know how to resolve these problems.

Comment: Gitlab is most probably running on a different port than the default port 22. You are connected to your host instead of gitlab.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider the default port used by gitlab server is the port 22 for ssh and i haven't found a config file in the .ssh directory of the git user that could override this.